# Add a rectangle to the image using image magic

Tags: ruby, imagemagick

Good day.
How to impose white_rectangle.jpg on logo.jpg in the image below
using Imagemagic. 
And a bonus question: what's Ruby's method can make the task.

```
def (path_to_image)
# impose white_rectangle.jpg on logo
end
```

[image: Removing logo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished using [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/):

```
require 'RMagick'

logo = Magick::Image.read("logo.jpg").first
rect = Magick::Image.read("white_rectangle.jpg").first
result = logo.composite(rect, x, y, Magick::CopyCompositeOp)
result.write "result.jpg"
```

An alternative is to just draw a white rectangle without using a composite image:

```
image = Magick::Image.read("logo.jpg").first
gc = Magick::Draw.new
gc.stroke = 'white'
gc.fill = 'white'
gc.rectangle x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end
gc.draw(image)
image.write "result.jpg"
```

Using ImageMagick command line tools, you can overlay one image with another like this:

```
$ composite white_rectangle.jpg logo.jpg -geometry +x+y result.jpg
```

Comment: what parameters (rect, x, y) should be set for image which I've attached ?

Comment: `rect` is the object holding the actual image in white_rectangle.jpg. For the position, just experiment until you get it right.